# How to wait until a value changes to true then continue running the other requests with RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

There is a function that must run 3 requests in a row, and it is not possible to know how many of them failed or succeeded. If the request fails, sending requests should stop and the user should click an ignore button.
After pressing the button, the execution of missed requests must be continued.

I hope you can help me, how can I handle this situation.

Thanks in advance.

```
requests = {
    X: "xyz.com"
    Y: "abc.com"
    Z: "qwe.com"
}
```

I tried to implement it with following:

```
from(Object.values(requests))
    .pipe(
        concatMap((action$: Observable<any>) => {
            return action$.pipe(
                            map(response => response), 
                            catchError(() => {
                    this.hasError = true;
                    return of(undefined);
                    }));
            }),
                takeWhile(() => !this.hasError),
            scan((resp1, resp2) => resp1.concat(resp2), []),
    )
    .subscribe(
        value => {
            console.log('value =', value);
        },
        error => {
            console.log('error = ', error);
        },
        () => {
            console.log('COMPLETE');
        }
    );
```

This is running until the first request fails, but it doesn't continue after that.

I tried to find a waitUntil operator, but unfortunately there is not found.

For example:

- How it is working now:

```
1. X request status -> 200
2. Y request status -> 404 - So in this case complete shutdown occurs ( by the takeWhile ) and no continuation occur after setting the "hasError" value to "false"

FYI: The next request should be the Z, after clicking on the "ignore" button.
```

- How it should work:

```
Example #1: 

1. X request status -> 200
2. Y request status -> 404 - Wait until the user clicks on the "ignore" button
3. Click on the "ignore" button
4. Z request status -> 200
5. All three values arrive in the "subscribe" section, so one value should be undefined and two should be the requested response values.

Example #2: 

1. X request status -> 404 - Wait until the user clicks on the "ignore" button
2. Click on the "ignore" button
3. Y request status -> 200
4. Z request status -> 404 - Wait until the user clicks on the "ignore" button
5. Click on the "ignore" button
6. All three values arrive in the "subscribe" section, so two value should be undefined and one should be the requested response value.
```

I hope you can help me, how can I handle this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to wait until the user clicked ignore? Can he also "abort"/"cancel" everything? If yes, I would make it three separate requests (independent of each other) and handle the status-logic separately. Temporally save the values and only allow the next request to happen, when the user allows it. If no, why not make all requests directly? You can still show a "ignore"-button to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty close.  Instead of returning `of()` inside `catchError`, you should return an observable that emits when the user has confirmed:

```js
  items$ = from(this.itemIds).pipe(
    concatMap(id => this.itemService.get(id).pipe(
      catchError(() => this.promptUser(id).pipe(map(() => undefined)))
    )),
    reduce((all, item) => all.concat(item), [])
  );
```

Per your description, I think you want [`reduce`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/reduce) instead of [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan). `reduce` will only emit once, whereas `scan` will emit each time it receives a value.

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74562057?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&devtoolsheight=60) demo.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "reduce" resolved the issue.

Comment: @nnn just `toArray()`

Comment: Yeah, you’re right, using toArray instead of reduce is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

1. create `ignore$` Subject
2. `catchError` return `ignore$.pipe(take(1))` to wait user click

```
const ignore$ = new Subject<undefined>();

function click() {
  ignore$.next(undefined);
}

from(Object.values(requests)).pipe(
  concatMap((action$: Observable<any>) => 
    action$.pipe(
      map(response => response),
      catchError(() => ignore$.pipe(take(1))),
    )
  ),
  toArray(),
).subscribe(...);
```